# CIImage: How to check if the image orientation was changed with objective-C OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ciimage

I am trying to change the orientation of the image (CIImage *myImage) but it looks it did not take any effect.

```
CIImage *myImage2 = [myImage imageByApplyingOrientation:kCGImagePropertyOrientationUp];
```

I tried also other ways:

```
CIImage *myImage2 = [myImage imageByApplyingOrientation:[@"1" intValue]];

CIImage *myImage2 = [myImage imageByApplyingTransform:[myImage imageTransformForOrientation:[@"5" intValue]]];
```

When I am trying to find out whether the orientation was changed:

```
NSLog(@"Image orientation %@",[[myImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation]);
```

I got "null". Tried as well to save "myImage2" to a new image but there is no effect after opening it. It looks that the method "imageByApplyingOrientation" does not work at all.

Comment: Is the image in question attached to a UIImageView? If not, it will be difficult to track the orientation. I would perhaps check the width and height; if width > height you can assume the image is landscape and visa versa.

Comment: It is not attached to an UIImageView. The orientation is a property of the image, so, perhaps, it should be bound with the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might try experimenting with the orientation value.  I noticed that using a value of "1" on my image had no effect either, but using something other than "1" did.  In my case, the value "6" ('Right, top' according to the docs) turned out to be what I needed.   I never checked the ciimage properties attribute, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: It seems that, regardless of the orientation information on the image, the "imageByApplyingOrientation" assumes your image is already upright.